# Boot Windows again after installing Linux

Tags: boot, uefi, partitioning

This is rather a linux than an Ubuntu question, but I don't really know the right forum for this:

I had Windows on /dev/sdb and Linux on /dev/sda without dual boot, so when I needed Windows, I went into the Bios by hitting F2 at bootup and chose Windows. I thought it was all decoupled until I reinstalled a new linux on sda, now the Bios cannot find Windows anymore, the Windows-option is gone :(

Boot-repair couldn't fix it, and I am too newby to know what is wrong. I created the bootinfo here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nsJ3fDV9sq/ .

I would love tho have the Windows-option in the Bios again, dual-boot is always broken on my PC after the "big" updates of Windows 10.

Does anyone know the solution to this, or is it all lost and I need to reinstall stuff?

Comment: Good thing you keep backups.   Have you tried the repair mode of the Windows install disk?  It should be able to repair the Windows boot.  I have seen systems like this where to use Windows you just let it boot, but to use Linux you boot from USB.

Comment: This is an Ubuntu forum, looks like you are using Manjaro Linux. For help you can ask on http://superuser.com/. But even though you had Windows main install on sdb, your ESP - efi boot partition was on sda and it looks like you erased it with your Linux install. As posted above you need your Windows repair disk to recreate UEFI boot files & folders in the ESP on sda.

Comment: Installation is a bit of a mess. It looks like Windows might be on sdb2,  but it's described as *Windows/Linux Data partition*. It's impossible to know what's in there unless you boot up in Linux and mount it. If it is just data, and no OS, then you will have to reinstall Windows. But sdb3 is described as a Windows Recovery partition, so you might be able to recover Windows from that. At the moment it doesn't look like you have a Windows OS, but check contents of sdb2.